# How to add an image in Yew?

Tags: rust, yew, trunk-rs

I am building a simple web app with Rust and I am trying to display an image to the website. But I can't add that image.

I am using Rust with a framework called [Yew](https://yew.rs/) and with a tool [Trunk](https://trunkrs.dev/).

> I have successfully linked the .scss file to my website with [Trunk](https://trunkrs.dev/). As they described in [their documentation](https://trunkrs.dev/assets/#sass-scss).

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Yew Development</title>
    <link data-trunk="" rel="scss" href="main.scss"> <!-- Successfull linked to this file -->
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

The .scss file does its work successfully.

But how can I display an image with Rust file with the `html!` macro?

**main.rs**

```
use yew::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    yew::start_app::<App>();
}

#[function_component(App)]
fn app() -> Html {
    html! {
        <>
            <h1> {"Hello world!"}</h1>
            <link data-trunk="true" rel="copy-file" href="img/rust.png"/> // doesn't work
            <img data-trunk="true" src="img/rust.png" alt="rust image"/> // doesn't work
            <img src="img/rust.png" alt="rust image"/> // doesn't work
        </>
    }
}
```

> Trunk's docs about [how to add image](https://trunkrs.dev/assets/#images-other-resources).

But the doc wasn't helpful for me.

Answer (score 21):

What you must do is instruct trunk to copy your static assets into the `dist` directory.

Let's suppose you have a directory called `img` with all the images, next to your `src` directory at the root of your project:

```
/home/me/code/my-yew-test
 ├──Cargo.lock 
 ├──Cargo.toml 
 ├──index.html 
 ├──src 
 │  └──main.rs 
 └──img 
    └──rust.png
```

Add this line to your `index.html` header:

```
<link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="img">
```

This line won't be present in the production `index.html` file, it's only an instruction for trunk.

Now the files of the `img` directory will be served by trunk (and copied into the `dist` directory for production) so you can have this link in your `html!` macro:

```
<img src="img/rust.png" alt="rust image"/>
```

`data-trunk` attributes here would make no sense: trunk only reads and parses the `index.html` file, it doesn't see what's generated client side by the wasm code produced by the `html!` macro.

Your dist directory will look like this:

```sh
    /home/me/code/my-yew-test
     ├──Cargo.lock 
     ├──Cargo.toml 
     ├──dist 
     │  ├──dysp-8a629f50b28a5e37.css 
     │  ├──index-8c2be3ebf3bd7075.js 
     │  ├──index-8c2be3ebf3bd7075_bg.wasm 
     │  ├──index.html 
     │  └──img
     │     └──rust.png
     ├──index.html 
     ├──src 
     │  └──main.rs 
     └──img 
        └──rust.png
```

Answer (score 8):

All `<link data-trunk ... />` elements **must be in the static HTML files** (such as index.html), not in the dynamically generated virtual DOM nodes via `html!`. This is because Trunk runs as a back-end process to determine what exactly is distributed as part of the main application, and this is a process which must be done in advance.

Attempting to add a `link` element afterwards would be an attempt to include an asset as part of the application after Trunk already did its job of copying and processing the expected assets, so it does not work. Instead, define all assets that you are going to need in your index.html, preferably in the `head` element, then you will be free to use them in your application by path (e.g. `image/rust.png`).

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is make the path ***relative***. Say this is your directory structure:

```
/home/me/code/my-yew-test
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── index.html
├── img
│   └── rust.png
├── README.md
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

In the `index.html` file you should add a relative folder/file path to the resource you want compied. For copying the whole folder and using the image in main.rs:

```html
<!--in index.html-->
<link data-trunk rel="copy-dir" href="./img"/>
```

```rust
// in main.rs
html!{
    <img src="img/rust.png" alt="rust image"/> 
}
```